# Laravel define abilities on a model other than User

Tags: php, laravel

On my application I use the default Laravel ACL to define abilities for the users, associated with a Role and Permissions subsequently.

I have a hasMany and a belongsTo relationship set up, in which a User belongs to a Company model and a Company has many Users. I would like to define "types" of companies which have different abilities, separately from the User abilities. For example, a company might be an "Architect" company with different abilities than a "Contractor" company, while each company has a User with a role of "Company Administrator", which can add or delete users from their company, and a bunch of "Regular" users.

Right now I have working the part in which a user can have a role, but I am a little bit lost on how to implement the Company "type or role". I am thinking that I must create my own `AuthServiceProvider`, name it something else and register it within laravel service providers, along with my own implementation of Gate that injects the Company model instead of the User?

Right now I am defining my User abilities in my AuthServiceProvider, and checking using the `Gate` Facade, for example:

Register Abilities in AuthServiceProvider.

```
//AuthServiceProvider

/**
 * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate $gate
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    parent::registerPolicies($gate);

    foreach ($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {

        $gate->define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {

            return $user->hasPermission($permission);
        });
    }
}
```

Then check User abilities on UserController.

```
//UserController

/**
 * Edit the user's email.
 *
 * @param User $user
 */
public function edit(User $user)
{
    if(Gate::allows('edit', $user){

        $user->email = $this->request->input('email');

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able of doing the same kind of checks with the Company model, i.e.:

```
// Check if the Company that the user belongs to is allowed to create posts

CompanyGate::allows('create-post');
```

Comment: Could you not continue to inject the User and then query the Company relationship on the User?

Comment: What I am trying to do is check the company abilities in several locations of my application. For example, an "Architect" company might create a post but a "Contractor" company may not.

Comment: Can you post some example code where you might be checking these abilities

Comment: @MattMcDonald I updated to show how I register and check for the User model abilities, I would like to be able of checking abilities the same way for the Company model.

Comment: So a company will be authenticated into your app? Or will a User be authenticated into your app, and that User belongs to a Company?

Comment: @MattMcDonald Correct, A user will be authenticated, and the User belongs to a company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently on your `User` model you seem to have defined a `hasPermission` function.

You can simply create a similar method on your `Company` model which checks the roles and permissions of a given company.

If you want to use `Gate` you still need to check permissions via the authenticated user, it is always going to validate permissions in the context of the authenticated user - but as the user belongs to a company you can then hop along to the company's permissions.

Something similar to the following:

```
$gate->define('create-post', function ($user) {

    return $user->company->hasPermission('create-post');
});
```